# Import Complex XML file into SQL server

Tags: sql-server, xml, import

I have about 6000 XML files need to import into SQL Database. I need to find out some fields in those XML files and import into multiple tables. Those files are InfoPath files saved as XML docs. Each file have about 20 fields need to go into 6 tables at respective columns. I analyzed the data fields and created tables and relation between them. Now, have to start importing the data.

I tried using XML source in SSIS but the data is too complex for SSIS to hold. So, xml source will not work for me. Worked on using Script task but I'm not core C#/VB developer. Also tried to use Bulk Insert; but **i don't have bulk insert permissions.** Friend suggested me to use XQuery,but i think Xquery works for parsing if the XML file is in table(Not sure).

Can anyone please tell me the best approach to start this task.

Thanks in Advance!

Kumar

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar scenario and here is approach I used:
1. create tables to hold xml data (with columns as xml data type)
2. read source xml files as TEXT and insert them into those tables
3. use XQuery in stored procedure to extract data and populate target tables

I can provide more pointers/information if you need.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I imported all xml files into table of XML type column. I tried with XQuery to extract fields from those files on xml column. but problem is if i write a query with some Path to get particular field i cant apply that same Path for all files to get 
same fields because for complexity in files. Can you please provide me some pointers.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to achieve this is to use the Open Source tool - [**Talend Open Studio**](http://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=21727)